# Navbar going up and down in a loop automatically

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

[image]

This is a website I designed for a TEDx Event at my school. It works for a desktop. However, on an iPhone, the bootstrap navbar I've made is going up and down in a loop. My guess is that this is happening on the home page because I added a Codepen code for a gift box opening animation. After I click any link, the website keeps loading infinitely (page keeps refreshing but webpage is never loaded). I've tried the metatag for specifying refresh, but it doesn't work

Here is the link for the website:
http://tedxyouthjpis.com

The animation on the home page is the code I borrowed from Codepen.

Comment: I do not see any code here!

Comment: it does not work on desktop...the nav items are blinking on desktop, changing the `#navbarCollapse` div's class to `collapsing` `collapse in` and `collapsed` when you hover the items. Better check you `js` to see why your code is change the class in loop. (you can also post it here for us to help)